# Excel If numbers end with '00'

Tags: excel, if-statement

Could you please help me write a IF formula so if a number end with '00' then output is A, else B. I wrote the following but it shows up as a #NAME?.

```
=IF((RIGHT(J3,2))="00",A,B)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `""` around the A and B as they are text:

```
=IF(RIGHT(J3,2)="00","A","B")
```